# onClick handler to call Material UI dialog box, is not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, material-ui, buttonclick

I want the material-ui dialog-box always pop up on button click and show the target value perfectly everytime. It shows sometimes but sometimes doesn't. I am sending the value on the icon onclick event - (e) and using it on the onClick function. I'm doing it on **react.js**. Is there a bug in the component?

I just found out that it's not the dialog component problem I was getting.
I'm not getting the value sometimes on **console.log** in the **openFunc** function while tapping on the icon.

**Had the same problem? Any help?**

Having the following code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import BorderColor from 'material-ui/svg-icons/editor/border-color';

class Mydialog extends Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
         ids:['129', '105', '131', '151'],
         myid: '',
         open_dialog: false
      }
      this.openFunc = this.openFunc.bind(this);
   }
   check_today() {
      let container = [];
      let i;

      for(i=0; i<this.state.ids.length;i++) {
         container.push(
                <BorderColor onClick = {this.openFunc} data-id ={this.state.ids[i]}/>
         )
      }

      if(container.length === 0){
        return(
            <div>show none!</div>
            )
      }
      else{
        return (
          <table>
            <tr>
                {container}
            </tr>
          </table>  
        )
      }
   }
   openFunc(e) {
      console.log(e.target.dataset.id);
      this.setState({
         open_dialog: true,
         myid: e.target.dataset.id
      });
   }
   handleClose = () => {
      this.setState({open_dialog: false});
   };
   render() {
      return(
        <div>
          <div>
           {this.check_today()}
          </div>
          <Dialog
           autoDetectWindowHeight={true}
           modal={false}
           open={this.state.open_dialog}
           onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
          >
           <div>
             It's the dialog-box!
             My id is {this.state.myid}
           </div>
          </Dialog>
        </div>
      )
   }
}
export default Mydialog
```

Comment: It's difficult to answer without looking at the code. Just add the part of the code which gives some more clarity about your question. Thanks.

Comment: Part of the code is given @NarasimhaReddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of relying on `data-id` for the value you can pass the value to the onClick function using the `Es6 arrow function syntax` as

```
<BorderColor onClick = {() => this.openFunc(this.state.ids[i])}/>
```

or the `bind` syntax as

```
<BorderColor onClick = {this.openFunc.bind(this, this.state.ids[i]} />
```

and use it in `openFunc` like

```
openFunc(value) {
  this.setState({
     open_dialog: true,
     myid: value
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things stand out;

First of all, items in an array of the same type require a key property to differentiate them from one another.  It is necessary to add this simply as follows;

```
for(i=0; i<this.state.ids.length;i++) {
     container.push(
            <BorderColor key={i} onClick={this.openFunc} data-id=this.state.ids[i]}/>
     )
  }
```

Also, while you certainly could use the data-id value, it's not the "react way".  I would recommend changing it to use a curried function.

Change `openFunc` to be this;

```
openFunc(id) {
    return (e) => {
        this.setState({
           open_dialog: true,
           myid: id
        });
}
```

Which you can then apply to the BorderColor component as such;

```
for(i=0; i<this.state.ids.length;i++) {
     container.push(
            <BorderColor key={i} onClick={this.openFunc(this.state.ids[i])}/>
     )
  }
```